# Why can't I change the value of a multidimensional char array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array, char

I'm making a TicTacToe game in C++ after watching Coding Train make it in his video using JavaScript. I'm not new to programming but I'm new to C++.

The problem arose when I tried to change a 2D char variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

constexpr unsigned int board_x = 3, board_y = 3;
const std::string divider = "--------------------------------------------------";

char board[board_x][board_y]
{
    {'-', '-', '-'},
    {'-', '-', '-'},
    {'-', '-', '-'}
};

std::vector<std::string> available_locations{ "A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", "C3" };

bool is_location_valid(const std::string&);
void change_board(std::string, unsigned short);
void print_available_locations();
void print_board();
void switch_turn(unsigned short&);
void take_turn(unsigned short&, std::string&);

int main()
{
    unsigned short player_turn = 1;
    std::string user_input;

    print_available_locations();
    take_turn(player_turn, user_input);
}

bool is_location_valid(const std::string& input)
{
    for (std::string& available_location : available_locations)
    {
        if (available_location == input) return true;
    }

    std::cout << "Unknown location" << std::endl << std::endl;
    return false;
}

void change_board(std::string input, const unsigned short player_turn)
{
    if (input.find('A') == 0) input[0] = '1';
    else if (input.find('B') == 0) input[0] = '2';
    else if (input.find('C') == 0) input[0] = '3';

    board[static_cast<int>(input[0]) - 1][static_cast<int>(input[1]) - 1] = player_turn == 1 ? 'X' : 'O';
}

void print_available_locations()
{
    std::cout << "Available location: ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < available_locations.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i != available_locations.size() - 1) std::cout << available_locations[i] << ", ";
        else std::cout << available_locations[i] << ".\n";
    }
}

void print_board()
{
    for (char(&i)[3] : board)
    {
        for (char j : i)
        {
            std::cout << j << "\t";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void switch_turn(unsigned short& player_turn)
{
    switch (player_turn)
    {
        case 1:
            player_turn = 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            player_turn = 1;
            break;
        default:
            player_turn = 1;
            break;
    }
}

void take_turn(unsigned short& player_turn, std::string& user_input)
{
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Player " << player_turn << ", enter board location...\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, user_input);
    } while (!is_location_valid(user_input));

    change_board(user_input, player_turn);
    print_board();
    std::cout << divider << std::endl;
    switch_turn(player_turn);
}
```

I don't know why but `board[static_cast<int>(input[0]) - 1][static_cast<int>(input[1]) - 1] = player_turn == 1 ? 'X' : 'O';` doesn't seem to change the `board` variable on top. What should I add or change to make it work?

Comment: Try (input[0] - '1') instead of (static_cast<int>(input[0]) - 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to assume that `static_cast<int>('1')` is 1. That is not the case. Characters are encoded by integer values and regardless of the encoding that your system uses, the value that is used to represent the character '1' is not 1.

In the ubiquitous ASCII encoding, '1' is represented by the value 49. The index 49-1 i.e. 48 is way outside the bounds of your array.

One possible fix:

```
input[0] = 1
```

Alternative fix:

```
board[input[0] - '1']
```

These fixes are exclusive.